# Virtual Video Cards?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, video-editing

The Conexant video card of my motherboard is not up to the task of video editing. Is there a virtual video card program that can enhance or replace my existing video card?  As my system has 16 gigs of RAM, memory shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Are you sure that's the video card? I distinctly don't recall them making any. They do make a uncommon sound chip tho

Answer (score 0):

Unless your graphics card is considerably below the spec of the rest of your system, moving the task from GPU to CPU is going to be even slower than at present.

Some apps can selectively move parts of a task - in 3D apps, things like shaders & skinning, from GPU to CPU for a better experience on very slow cards, but I'm not sure what could be done to accelerate any kind of 2D task in a similar way.